# Is it possible to access Jenkins slave machine's files?

Tags: linux, build, jenkins, unity-game-engine

I have Jenkins master installed in cloud service in linux server. I have also installed Jenkins in my local machine (Windows). The local machine version of Jenkins is working as a slave. Slave setup is configured in master location. The connection between them works fine.

I have a plugin in Jenkins master where I need to provide an application directory. This application directory is located only in my slave machine. So I would like to know that is it possible to tell to Jenkins master that the application directory is located at slave machine? If yes how it is done?

I have been searching in Google, but not found any solution yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Copy to Slave plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Copy+To+Slave+Plugin) allows copying to and from a Slave to Master